# Firestore - Check if the document which is being updated exists

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As far as I know - In order to check whether a `document` exists or not, I should use the `get` function and see if it does.

**My question is about checking while updating - Is it possible?** (Considering that the `document` might be gone when the update occurs).

I have tried to update an empty `document` and I got an error which says that the document doesn't exist, but I think this might not be the successful way to check this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are a few ways to write data to Cloud Firestore:

- **update()** - change fields on a document that already exists. Fails if the document does not exist.
- **set()** - overwrite the data in a document, creating the document if it does not already exist. If you want to only partially update a document, use `SetOptions.merge()`.
- **create()** - only available in the server-side SDKs, similar to `set()` but fails if the document already exists.

So you just need to use the correct operation for your use case.  If you want to update a document without knowing if it exists or not, you want to use a `set()` with the `merge()` option like this (this example is for Java):

```
// Update one field, creating the document if it does not already exist.
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("capital", true);

db.collection("cities").document("BJ")
        .set(data, SetOptions.merge());
```

Comment: Can you write this one in Java? I'm using Firebase for Android actually.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask you what I have asked under the answer above: Can I detect if the operation failed specifically because the document doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, in the Android client the failure comes as a [FirebaseFirestoreException][1] which contains a [Code][2]. In this case you'll see Code.ALREADY_EXISTS.

[1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException
[2]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code

Comment: Will update still fail if a field does not exist in the document? So if I had a document {firstname: "John"} and i call doc.update({lastname: "Doe"}) would that be ok?

Comment: @DevShadow that will succeed.

Comment: In Javascript, the second argument is simply an Object, so it would become:
`db.collection("cities").document("BJ").set(data, {merge: t rue});` I am writing it here because this question is the first result on Google for `firestore update if exists`

Answer (score 9):

If you only want to perform an update if the document exists, using `update` is exactly the thing to do. The behavior you observed is behavior you can count on.

We specifically designed this so that it's possible to perform a partial update of a document without the possibility of creating incomplete documents your code isn't otherwise prepared to handle.

Comment: So should I read the message in OnFailure and than detect if it's occured because the document doesn't exist? Is there a good way to detect if the update failed specifically because of this?

Comment: @TalBarda see below.  You should write data using the appropriate operation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to try to update a document that does not exist is:

```
try {
  await db.collection('cities').doc('BJ').update('key', 'value')
} catch (error) {
  // document not exists, do nothing  
}
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me try and catch. here is an example for firestore:     try {
      return await updateDoc(refDoc, {
        allocatedInProjects: increment(1)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      return await setDoc(refDoc, {
        allocatedInProjects: 1
      })
    }

Answer (score 0):

We can go with update and set the mask parameter to true
like this: -

```
firestore.updateDocument("GFrom/"+data.email,data, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in such type of scenario the **set()** with **merge: true** is the best option to use.
**Using Flutter**

```
firestoreInstance.collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).set(
{
"username" : "userX",
},SetOptions(merge: true))
```