# Firestore create document if it doesn't exist security rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I was trying to write a rule that if the id of the document doesn't exist, then create a new document. My object is:

```
Message message = new Message(userId, title, messageBody, timestamp);
```

and I'm using `WriteBatch` to create a new document and updating the same:

```
mWriteBatch.set(mMessageRef.document(messageId), message);

mWriteBatch.update(mMessageRef.document(mIntentMessageId), // params...);
```

After browsing through the docs and this site I've found out that if I use `create` method, it only [allows to write the data if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46697671/2519748).

So I created a security rule like:

```
match /messages/{message} {
  allow read; 
  allow create: if isSignedIn();
  allow update, delete: if isSignedIn();
}
```

`isSignedIn()` is just a method contianing `request.auth != null`. This rule fails and overwrites the data. Now I tried:

```
match /messages/{message} {
  allow read; 
  allow create: if request.resource.id != message;
  allow update, delete: if isSignedIn();
}
```

This time also it overwrites the data instead of showing an error.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

**Update:** As told by José David Aroesti in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52341836/2519748), I have to change it to `exists` and remove `update` and `delete` to work properly and from the app it's reflecting what it's suppose to do. But then how would I `update` and `delete` a document?

For example, when I'm using the below rules in Simulator, both are being executed as expected but when I'm testing it from the device, I'm always able to create a document even if it exists:

```
allow create: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/messages/$(message));

allow update: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/messages/$(message)).data.timestamp
        < request.resource.data.timestamp;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It should be impossible to overwrite if you have **not specified** `write` or `update`.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot updated the question, I've also included update and delete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `exists()` and `get()` built-in functions to verify if the document exists or to access the document so you can read its data.

In this case, an example would be:

```
match /messages/{message} {
    allow read; 
    allow create: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/messages/$(request.resource.id));
}
```

And as @creativecreatorormaybenot suggested, you should not specify `allow` expressions for `update` and `delete` so the data cannot be overwritten.

Here is a link to the documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore

Comment: Thank you. Previously I was comparing with request.resource.id to get method. As suggested I removed `update` and `delete` and saw the difference. But now how am I going to update or delete a document? Any help?